# what is the use of .next field in sched_class structure?

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduling, scheduler

> sched_class next value points to different scheduler class like
>   stop_sched_class->next points to rt_sched_class , rt_sched_class->next
>   points to fair_sched_class , fair_sched_class->next points to
>   idle_sched_class , idle_sched_class->next points to NULL;

I am getting confused whether all scheduling algorithms are working at the same time or not. If they work at the same time then it would be unfair.

What is the use of next field? (kernel version 3.12)

Answer (score 2):

The "next" pointer is to implement an intrusive singly-listed list.  It's intrusive in that the "next" pointer is right alongside the regular data, rather than in some separate "node" structure like some textbook SLL implementations would do (and like the C++ STL does).  Intrusive is efficient, and fairly common in C.

As for why there is a linked list of schedulers, see here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/